# Run a specific TestNG XML test suite with Gradle from command line?

Tags: gradle, testng

I am using Gradle with TestNG. I have this build.gradle:

```
useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = true
        suites "src/test/resources/tests1.xml"
        suites "src/test/resources/tests2.xml"
   }
}
```

How can I run for example only tests1.xml from command line?

Answer (score 8):

you can use project properties to add/change/... different suites. In you example you are probably running

```
gradlew test
```

which run both suites. If you modify test task in your build.gradle

```groovy
def suite1 = project.hasProperty("suite1")
def suite2 = project.hasProperty("suite2")

test {
    useTestNG() {
        dependsOn cleanTest
        useDefaultListeners = true

        if(suite1) {
            suites "src/test/resources/simpleSuite.xml"
        }

        if(suite2) {
            suites "src/test/resources/advancedSuite.xml"
        }
    }
}
```

you can choose suite in this way

```
gradlew test -Psuite1
gradlew test -Psuite2
gradlew test -Psuite1 -Psuite2
```

Answer (score 5):

you can specify variable let say `suiteFile` with default value and use it in testNG section. For example:

```groovy
ext{
    
    set suiteFile, default is 'testrun_config.xml'
    if (!project.hasProperty('suiteFile')) {
        suiteFile = 'testrun_config.xml'
    }
}

test {
    useTestNG() {
        dependsOn cleanTest
        useDefaultListeners = true
        suites "src/test/resources/"+suiteFile
       
    }
}
```

Refer qaf [gradle build file](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project-gradle/blob/master/build.gradle)

If you want to pass through command line

```
gradlew test -PsuiteFile=test.xml
```

Comment: This is the best answer, versus the other ones that hardcode nicknames in the `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 3):

In build.gradle update:

```groovy
test {
    useTestNG() {
        if (project.hasProperty('suite1')) { suites './src/test/suite1.xml' }
        if (project.hasProperty('suite2')) { suites './src/test/suite2.xml' }
    }
}
```

Use command `gradlew test -Psuite1` to run suite1 and similarly update for suite2 as well.

Comment: what if I run `gradlew test -Psuite1 -Psuite2`? It will overwrite or append?

Answer (score 1):

### under src/test/java must have a @test method

#### edite build.gradle add this

```
def hasSuite = project.hasProperty("suite")
def hasSuitePath = project.hasProperty("suitepath")

test {
    useTestNG() {
        dependsOn cleanTest
        useDefaultListeners = true

        if( hasSuite) {
            def suiteName = project.property('suite')
            suites "src/test/resources/${suiteName}"
        }

        if( hasSuitePath ){
            def suitepath = project.property("suitepath")
            suites "${suitepath}"
        }
    }
}
```

#### then

```
./gradlew test -Psuite=login.xml

./gradlew test -Psuitepath=src/main/resources/login.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this in your test task:

```
def suite = project.properties.getOrDefault("suite", "testng.xml")
        useTestNG() {
            suites "src/test/resources/suites/${suite}"
        }
```

That means you have default value for property suite. In case you need to override it just call.

```
gradle clean test -Psuite=suiteName.xml
```

If you don't need it - call:

```
gradle clean test
```

And default property value will be used