# Run specific testNG test with Gradle on different test environments

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, gradle, automated-tests, testng

I am running testNG with gradle:

```
 doFirst {
        systemProperty 'baseURL', project.ext.getProperty('baseURL')
    }
useTestNG {
        suites '/src/test/resources/browserconfigone.xml'
        suites '/src/test/resources/browserconfigtwo.xml'
    }
```

i want to run these suites in different environemnts e.g. browserconfigone.xml just in dev environment and browserconfigtwo.xml just in test environment.

i am setting URL like this

```
task qa(type: Test) {
    doFirst {
        project.ext.setProperty("baseURL", 'https://ticketed-website.test.com')
    }
```

how would i configure each suite to run a diff environment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606992/run-a-specific-testng-xml-test-suite-with-gradle-from-command-line